# Launching background tasks in a remote session that don't get killed when the session is removed

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, psexec, powershell-remoting

I have been using `PsExec -d` to launch console applications in a remote powershell session because I want these apps to run in the background while I perform some task. The problem is that I want the background applications to continue running even if I kill the remote powershell session with `Remove-PSSession`. What happens currently is once the remote powershell session is killed so are all the processes that were started with the help of `PsExec -d`. I'm guessing it has something to do with process trees and how windows manages the lifetime of such things.

Does anyone have any idea how I can launch a remote background process and have that process persist even after the remote session is killed?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is first an explanation of why it works so. Perhaps someone else can use it to bring a another solution.

I edited my answer with solution based on WMI.

When you enter a remote session :

```
PS C:\Users\JPB> enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.183.100 -Credential $cred
[192.168.183.100]: PS C:\Users\jpb\Documents>
```

You create on the server a process called `wsmprovhost.exe` as shown here under

[image]

When you simply start a process in this remote session :

```
[192.168.183.100]: PS C:\Users\jpb\Documents> Start-Process calc.exe
```

The new process is a child of `wsmprovhost.exe` as shown here under

[image]

If you stop the remote session `wsmprovhost.exe` disappeared and so the child process.

The explanation is that `wsmprovhost.exe` and all the processes started by this one belongs to the same job.

[image]

By default, on one hand this job DOES NOT supports `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK` limit flag that does not allow us to start a process with `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag, on the other hand this job supports `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` limit flag that causes all processes associated with the job to terminate when the last handle to the job is closed.

It perhaps exists a solution to configure WinRM to support jobs which supports `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_BREAKAWAY_OK`.

---

Edited :

So reading [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), I found a documented technical way for you to start a program through WinRM but in an onother job. By default, processes created using CreateProcess by a process associated with a job are associated with the job; however, processes created using *Win32_Process.Create* **are not associated with the job**.

So if in you remote session you create a process with WMI like this :

```
PS C:\silogix> $ps = New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.183.100 -Credential $cred
PS C:\silogix> Enter-PSSession -Session $ps
[192.168.183.100]: PS C:\Users\jpb\Documents> Invoke-WmiMethod -path win32_process -name create -argumentlist "calc.exe"



__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ProcessId        : 1236
ReturnValue      : 0

[192.168.183.100]: PS C:\Users\jpb\Documents> exit
PS C:\silogix> Remove-PSSession $ps
```

If you stop the remote session wsmprovhost.exe disappeared, but the new process stay on the server as show here under :

[image]

The processes started with WMI does not belongs to any Job. In french I would say "Ce qu'il fallait démontrer"

Comment: Thanks for the analysis JPBlanc. My current workaround is to simply use the remote sessions for collecting information that is used to launch processes with `PsExec -d` from outside the remote sessions. This way when the remote session is killed the process started with `PsExec -d` is not.

Comment: @davidk01 I think I found a clean solution, I edited my answer to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the great post. It saved me more hours of search how to do this.