# Powershell remote job getting killed after a few hours

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am running a remote job as part of a deployment which is supposed to run forever (seeding random data) however the process keeps getting killed after only a few hours.. I am figuring some missing remote service flag or something.

I am running the remote job via this powershell command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName DEPLY -Credential $cred -AsJob -ScriptBlock { 
    C:\Deply\${bamboo.Configuration}\Seed\Seed.exe /y 
}
```

Is there someway to prevent this process from being killed?

Comment: AFAIK jobs run indefinitely, this is also stated in the `Wait-Job` parameter `-Timeout`. This parameter has by default the value `-1`, so it should keep on waiting. Are you sure your `Seed.exe` isn't the one who stops working after a while?

Comment: Yeah - there is literally a white(true) in there.. lol.  I write the log files to disk too, no exceptions or odd behavior.. it just silently closes.

Comment: If you want to be sure if it is `Seed.exe` or not who stops the job, you can put some code after it, within the job. And check with `Get-Job | Receive-Job` in the end of your script, to see if you see that last piece of code in the output. If not... then you know it's the `Seed.exe` that's crashing. A `Try/Catch` might be an option to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to me there is just an undocumented kill timeout for powershell jobs.  I confirmed that my program is not crashing and the remoting service is just killing it after 3-4 hours.  Or maybe its an OS thing - I don't know.

I switched to [psexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) which doesn't mess with the process - here is the command:

`psexec \\DEPLY -accepteula -d -u "corp\administrator" -p "xxx" C:\Deply\${bamboo.Configuration}\Seed\Seed.exe /y`

You can also launch it via WMI like so:

`$process = get-wmiobject -query "SELECT * FROM Meta_Class WHERE __Class = 'Win32_Process'" -namespace "root\cimv2" -computername DEPLY -credential $cred
$results = $process.Create( "C:\Deply\${bamboo.Configuration}\Seed\Seed.exe /y" )`

But I can't confirm if a remote process created this way lasts forever.  Each test takes 4 hours and Im done messing with this.

RELATED: [Launching background tasks in a remote session that don't get killed when the session is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675847/launching-background-tasks-in-a-remote-session-that-dont-get-killed-when-the-se)