# Execute powershell command remotely to run in the background

Tags: windows, powershell, npm

I'm connecting to windows machine using ssh and trying to execute command to run in the background.
Running the following command from the terminal after ssh established works:

`start PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{"cd C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\myserver\; npm start > log.log 2>&1"}`

But what I really need is to run the following command and it doesn't work:

`ssh myuser@machine_ip "start PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{\"cd C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\myserver\; npm start > log.log 2>&1\"}"`

Running the second command without 'start' works but it 'holds' the terminal.
And basically it's not a must to work with powershell if someone can tell how to execute the below command and make it run in the background:
`cd C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\myserver\; npm start > log.log 2>&1`

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the Start-Job cmdlet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Why use invoke-command or powershell at all?

Comment: js2010, it's not mandatory at all, but this is the way I got to send the commands.
I've found a way to bypass this with 'bat' script and psexec, but it also stack the terminal for example: ssh myuser@machineIp psexec myscript.bat -d

Comment: @js2010 see my comment above

Comment: finally found how it works and the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675847/launching-background-tasks-in-a-remote-session-that-dont-get-killed-when-the-se/8704945#8704945

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this piece of code, but Invoke-Command has a command called -asjob.

```
ssh myuser@machine_ip "start PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{\"cd C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\myserver\; npm start > log.log 2>&1\"}" -AsJob
```

Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1#example-8--run-a-background-job-on-several-remote-computers